# How can I configure role of kie-workbench 7.0.0

Tags: configuration, drools, kie-workbench

Hellow, I can't find some menu of kie-workbench, so I ask something to do.

My enviroment is JDK 1.8.0 / wildfly 10.1 / kie-workbench 7.0.0.CR1.

This is my [kie-project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNzKn.png) screen and he is differnt from manual's screen. Most critical thing is I can't change other project.

Below is my installation step. Please check what I forget.

1. Using add-user.sh, I add three users.
2. Edit Web.xml, add some roles in [kie-workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZn9W.png) (But I am not confiure details in workbench)

I think more setting for web.xml, but I can't find how to set.

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

I deploy jBPM embedded war, they show all menu.

That is

First, I deploy workbench download from http://www.drools.org/download/download.html, I can't see all menu.

Second, I deploy workbench download from http://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html (jBPM embedded), I see all menu.

Also, I deploy workbench 7.0.0.CR3, I can change other project. So, that is bug of workbench of 7.0.0.CR1.